# How Wordpress understands what do with the (all) key in the $wp_filter array?

Tags: hooks

In the `isset( $wp_filter['all])`, the `all` key will fire for all other hooks. i need to know how Wordpress understands what to do if the key `all` is used.. It should be defined somewhere which make Wordpress understands it.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Hook names are not "built" or "defined" somewhere. You can call any hook name anywhere without that. And many hooks are not called in a function.

Comment: Ok ... so the question shloud be what is the hooks mechanism and how they work according to thw wordpress core it self? ..and I don't mean how to use it..

Comment: We have covered this a few times already. See [How do filters and hooks really work in PHP](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/how-do-filters-and-hooks-really-work-in-php), [Trouble understanding apply_filters()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/trouble-understanding-apply-filters) and [What is “all” in isset($wp_filter all )](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226552/what-is-all-in-issetwp-filterall). I think this question is a duplicate of the latter.

Comment: Thanks.. I will check these links and if I still have questios I will update mine... thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `all` explained in this function for instance

```
File: wp-includes/plugin.php
402: /**
403:  * Execute functions hooked on a specific action hook.
404:  *
405:  * This function invokes all functions attached to action hook `$tag`. It is
406:  * possible to create new action hooks by simply calling this function,
407:  * specifying the name of the new hook using the `$tag` parameter.
408:  *
409:  * You can pass extra arguments to the hooks, much like you can with apply_filters().
410:  *
411:  * @since 1.2.0
412:  *
413:  * @global array $wp_filter         Stores all of the filters
414:  * @global array $wp_actions        Increments the amount of times action was triggered.
415:  * @global array $wp_current_filter Stores the list of current filters with the current one last
416:  *
417:  * @param string $tag     The name of the action to be executed.
418:  * @param mixed  $arg,... Optional. Additional arguments which are passed on to the
419:  *                        functions hooked to the action. Default empty.
420:  */
421: function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
422:    global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $wp_current_filter;
423: 
424:    if ( ! isset($wp_actions[$tag]) )
425:        $wp_actions[$tag] = 1;
426:    else
427:        ++$wp_actions[$tag];
428: 
429:    // Do 'all' actions first
430:    if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) ) {
431:        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
432:        $all_args = func_get_args();
433:        _wp_call_all_hook($all_args);
434:    }
435: 
436:    if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
437:        if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
438:            array_pop($wp_current_filter);
439:        return;
440:    }
441: 
442:    if ( !isset($wp_filter['all']) )
443:        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
444: 
445:    $args = array();
446:    if ( is_array($arg) && 1 == count($arg) && isset($arg[0]) && is_object($arg[0]) ) // array(&$this)
447:        $args[] =& $arg[0];
448:    else
449:        $args[] = $arg;
450:    for ( $a = 2, $num = func_num_args(); $a < $num; $a++ )
451:        $args[] = func_get_arg($a);
452: 
453:    $wp_filter[ $tag ]->do_action( $args );
454: 
455:    array_pop($wp_current_filter);
456: }
```

The part:

```
429:    // Do 'all' actions first
```

Speaks `all` has the special treatment inside the hook generator functions.

The similar logic you will find in other hook generator functions:

```
apply_filters
apply_filters_ref_array
apply_filters_deprecated
do_action
do_action_ref_array
do_action_deprecated
```

So `all` has the special treatment.

You may use `all` for introspection as in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first/250293#250293) where I list all actions hooks in sequence order for a single WordPress request.

---

#### From the comments:

> I understand, but I want to know how WordPress understands that when passing this key all it will affect all actions or filters. It should be defined somewhere

Took me some time to understand what you meant. Yes. There is a global called `$wp_filter` in there all hooks are saved. In case of the example
`add_action( 'all', '_20161224_printer' );` [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first/250293#250293), this will be inside that global.

```
[all] => WP_Hook Object
        (
            [callbacks] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [_20161224_printer] => Array
                                (
                                    [function] => _20161224_printer
                                    [accepted_args] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [iterations:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [current_priority:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [nesting_level:WP_Hook:private] => 0
            [doing_action:WP_Hook:private] => 
        )
```

Comment: I understand , but i want to know how wordpress understands that when passing this key `all` it will affect all actions or filters.. it should be defined somewhers

Comment: @MohamedOmar, replied you as update to the original post.

Comment: Ok.. here is the point.. As you can see the `all` is an array.. This array has to be defined some where to have all hooks stored in ... that is what i want , where is the definition of the `all` array in the wordpress core

Comment: This is inside the `global $wp_filter` array @MohamedOmar

Comment: I know but i have searched the whole core about any definition to this and i just could find the `if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )` .. so there is an `isset` it has to be set some where ... where is the source code that makes the `all` array grabs filters

Comment: what would set the condition  `if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )` to true

Comment: ✓this and create a new question with that last specific details. I may try to answer.

Comment: done here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251182/where-is-the-source-code-that-makes-the-all-array-grabs-filters-in-the-wp-fil